# How can I add a constraint to a custom field I created?

Tags: 8

I have created a complex field type (my class extends `DateRangeItem`) that supports recurring dates by adding a property for storing an RRULE string:

```
class DateTimeRecurItem extends DateRangeItem {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    $properties = parent::propertyDefinitions($field_definition);
    // Prevent early t() calls by using the TranslatableMarkup.
    $properties['rrule_string'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(new TranslatableMarkup('RRule String'))
      ->setRequired(FALSE);

    return $properties;
  }

  ...
```

I want to validate the RRule string (there's a RFC to validate it against). I can do this by [creating a custom constraint](https://www.drupalwatchdog.com/volume-5/issue-2/introducing-drupal-8s-entity-validation-api) and applying it like this:

```
$properties['rrule_string'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
  ->setLabel(new TranslatableMarkup('RRule String'))
  ->setConstraint('MyCustomConstraint')
  ->setRequired(FALSE);
```

The problem is I also need to know the value for the `value` property of the field (which is inherited by `DateRangeItem`). Implemented as above, my constraint validator will only be passed the raw string value of the `rrule_string` property.

**I can't figure out how I can define a constraint that applies to the entire field** (thereby having access to all of its field properties). There seems to be no interface for doing that.

To be clear, this is not a field I've added to a custom entity definition. This is just a custom field I defined that can be added to any entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of a field type, you can simply put it in the annotation.

Have a look at FileItem for example:

```
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'file' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "file",
 *   label = @Translation("File"),
 *   description = @Translation("This field stores the ID of a file as an integer value."),
 *   category = @Translation("Reference"),
 *   default_widget = "file_generic",
 *   default_formatter = "file_default",
 *   list_class = "\Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileFieldItemList",
 *   constraints = {"ReferenceAccess" = {}, "FileValidation" = {}}
 * )
 */
class FileItem extends EntityReferenceItem {
```

Actually a bit surprised that the date classes don't have any constraints, that sounds like a bug.

Comment: Thanks! I originally looked at the `FieldType` annotation class but didn't see a defined property for `constraints` so I didn't think this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `getConstraints` method.

```
public function getConstraints() {
  $constraint_manager = \Drupal::typedDataManager()->getValidationConstraintManager();
  $constraints = parent::getConstraints();
  $constraints[] = $constraint_manager->create('CustomConstraint', array()); 
  return $constraints;
}
```

Comment: Alternatively `$constraint_manager = $this->getTypedDataManager()->getValidationConstraintManager()`